# How to select a single image from an Array of Image Literals and save it to user defaults in swift 5

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I am a very new Swift developer.

I have a global Array of Image Literals, displaying in an Image Scroll view.

I need a user to be able to select a single image and off a button, save it to user defaults.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

I cannot find any resources on this, using Image Literals.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: Hello Rob, I have the image literal array displaying in a image scroll view, but I cannot find any information on how to select a single image from the image scroll view when its an image literals array, so I have no code for that yet .. I just need someone to point me in the right direction, I've only been learning Swift for 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an image view, assign the image to it and then use:

```
let imageView.image = yourArray[imageIndex]

guard let imageData = imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1) else { return }


    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "imageKey")
```

Comment: The issue with this answer is the question *clearly* states that the user is picking a single image from an array (pretty standard), not an image view.

Comment: Is not an issue, just set a dummy imageView, the main question is how to store it to UserDefaults, not extracting it from an array

Comment: Well, you convinced me to downvote the question with your comment. My *very* different take was the main issue is picking an image literal from an array, *not* storing it in `UserDefaults`. Either way, there's a ton of resources for either one.

Comment: Well if he is already displaying an array of images, i assume he knows about arrays, that is why it makes more sense to think that he needs to know how to store them, but either way, my answer is updated.

Comment: I’m not arguing and did not downvoted you, i gave you a solution, just try it please and let me know.